# Getting Custom UserName Credentials in a WCF Method Call

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF Service with a binding endpoint with security mode set to "TransportWithMessageCredentials" and a custom UserNamePasswordValidator to handle the credential validations.  It's working fine.

Since the validation is addressed outside of the service operation/method, is it possible (and if so how) to get the name of the authenticated user from inside of the method?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name
```